# Make appsync introspection endpoint publicly available

Tags: authorization, aws-appsync

I have an AppSync GQL Api with default authorization mode `AuthorizationType.USER_POOL`
and additional authorization `AuthorizationType.API_KEY`

I would like to make the appsync introspection schema publicly available (or the  `query IntrospectionQuery { ...` publicly available.

Is that possible and if yes, how?

Comment: It should be the default. You can read this article on how to disable it to understand more: https://www.serverlessfanatic.cloud/hiding-your-appsync-graphql-introspection-endpoint-using-aws-web-application-firewall-waf-rules